# How to migrate from THREE.SceneLoader? r84

Tags: three.js

Currently at the tail end of a migration from `r69` to `r84` and I'm wondering what the best way would be to migrate from `THREE.SceneLoader` to either `THREE.JSONLoader` or `THREE.ObjectLoader`.

When I attempt to use the `JSONLoader` I get an error that I should use the `SceneLoader` instead, kind of strange considering it's been deprecated.

Looking at the source of `JSONLoader` I guess if the `type` of data coming in is `scene` then it will throw this error, but what should the type be and is `JSONLoader` even the right replacement?